# map Gson nested object to a different name

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have a Java class that has:

```
private String rgStatus;
private RGDepLimit rGDepLimit ;
```

I'm using Gson to serialize/deserialize to/from JSON objects. It works fine. My problem is that I am trying to serialize the object field `rGDepLimit` with a different name. I tried to use `@SerializedName("theNewName")`:

```
private String rgStatus;
@SerializedName("theNewName") 
private RGDepLimit rGDepLimit ;
```

but it always serializes to a `null` value for the `rGDepLimit` field.

### Output samples

#### 1 - Without `@SerializedName("theNewName")`

```
{...,"rGDepLimit ":{"value":9900000,"currency":"GBP","rgStatus":"ACTIVE","requestedTimeStamp":"1485936564000"}}
```

#### 2 - With `@SerializedName("theNewName")`

```
{...,"rGDepLimit ":null}
```

Comment: `rGDepLimit` could be null from your `getRGdepLimit` method. Meanwhile the `"theNewName"` key also exists

Comment: rGDepLimit is not null and the 'theNewName' does not exist

Comment: My point was that Gson also looks at the getters and setters.

Comment: @cricket_007 you was right when add the  @SerializedName("theNewName") to the rGDepLimit ,the getter return null .

Comment: Gson uses neither getters nor setters.

Comment: Make sure that your `rGDepLimit` is not `null` before serialization. `@SerializedName` should work fine.

Comment: LyubomyrShaydariv its not null before i used @SerializedName.i tested it many times and posted part of the result

Comment: @MeladEzzat If possible, try to set breakpoints for these lines: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java#L122 and https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java#L136 in order to verify the field values. These `field.get` statements should return `null` for your case. Which Gson version are you using?

Comment: Are you by any chance using custom serializers? That would prevent this from serializing correctly?